# Randomize 4 Colors and save C#

Tags: c#, random

I'm creating a Mastermind game where the user choses 4 out of 5 colors and see if it's a match.
It would then send the given color combination to the CheckClass to see if the combination is right.

My question is, how could i randomize 4 between Red, Blue, Yellow, Lime and Purple?

Would I have to randomize with the different color codes? 
This is what i've found so far:

```
private Color GetRandomColor()
{
return Color.FromArgb(random.Next(0, 255), random.Next(0, 255), random.Next(0, 255));
}
```

Which color codes should i use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an array of the desired colors and select a random one from them:

```
private Color GetRandomColor()
{
    Random r = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    var colorArray = new Color[] 
           { 
              Color.Red, 
              Color.Blue, 
              Color.Yellow, 
              Color.Lime, 
              Color.Purple 
           };
    return colorArray[r.Next(colorArray.Length-1)];
}
```

if you want 4 random color from five, every time you call the function, first shuffle the array in a loop, then return first 4 colors from it:

```
private Color[] GetRandomColor()
{
    Random r = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    var colorArray = new Color[] 
        { 
           Color.Red, 
           Color.Blue, 
           Color.Yellow, 
           Color.Lime, 
           Color.Purple 
         };
     for (int i = 0; i < colorArray.Length; i++)
     {
         var j = r.Next(colorArray.Length - 1);
         var k = r.Next(colorArray.Length - 1);
         var temp = colorArray[j];
         colorArray[j] = colorArray[k];
         colorArray[k] = temp;
     }
     return colorArray.Take(4).ToArray()
}
```

Comment: Would be better: "return colorArray[r.Next(colorArray.Length-1)];"

Comment: Thanks a lot! But will this generate a random order every time? Right now it shows up in the exact order the array was delcared.

Comment: I added a seed based on time, to generate more like random numbers

Comment: @martoo you could also declare `private Random r;` as a class member and initialise it in with `r = new Random();` in the class constructor. (Also change the name from `r` to something more meaningful to the reader.)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be if you have a defined set of color from where you need to choose randomly like one below

```
string[] listOfColors = { "RED", "BLUE", "GREEN", "YELLOW" };
```

you can try the following code to get the random color element

```
listOfColors[(new Random()).Next(0, listOfColors.Length)];
```

Comment: Besides this answer being the same as Alex Zhevzhik's comment, it should crash about once every four times it is run.